# How does update.zip work?

Tags: updates

`update.zip`s are packages containing replacements for parts of an Android system. The packages contain all the files the update is intended to replace and a script that will do the replacement when it's run.

`update.zip`s can come from OTA updates, but in some cases, it is necessary to manually download and put an `update.zip` in some special folder. However, the `update.zip` is still detected and applied in the same manner.

What part of Android detects and handles `update.zip`s?

Comment: Congratulations: someone made http://update.zip redirect here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`update.zip` are never touched by Android.

Inside that archive is a script that is parsed and interpreted by the Recovery runtime.

The Recovery, at execution, opens the archive by unzipping into a temporary directory, reads the script, aptly named `update-script`, analyzes it, and based on the syntax, executes a function known to Recovery, that function may do the following, to name but a few:

- mount `/system` and other filesystems, and perform read/write file operations  including, copying the kernel, or, an apk or even formatting a partition etc
- check the `build.prop` for certain properties, such as device, manufacturer, etc
- print display to the screen, progress information etc

It is pretty much a de-facto standard incorporated into Android Open Source Project (AOSP)

ClockworkMod, TWRP are derivatives of the barebones version that resides in AOSP with additional enhancements, such as touchscreen input.

Comment: +1 very interesting. So the recovery isn't part of android itself? What does it fall under? Part of Linux, a separate entity?

Comment: @RossC The proper Recovery environment, resides on a separate `/recovery` partition (some manufacturers do not do this for some unknown reason, pseudo recovery) barebones limited Android, depending if stock recovery,  limited shell vs CWM/TWRP which packs more, besides, root privileges. A real modder's delight is a device that has the separate partition for recovery.

Comment: `/recovery` doesn't look like a partition. In Linux that's just a directory. It *could* be a *mounted* partition - but it's still just a directory. I say this because it's a common misconception I've noticed in Android users.

Comment: @yannbane - try this,`cat /proc/mtd` or look at `/proc/partitions`, its how the bootloader works, if vol dwn is pressed, bootloader reads kernel from `/recovery` and chain loads it bringing up either stock or custom recovery.  It is *not* linux....